# How to store various types of data each day in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to store in CoreData various information each day as following:

day1: string, integer, integer, double, Boolean
day2: string, integer, integer, double, Boolean
day3: ....
up to several months.

I plan to do save it in CoreData due to the amount and type of information but I cannot find the best way to do it. I was thinking to use an Array but as it cannot contain various types what is the best way to do it?
Typically the user will enter such information every day, selecting the actual day on the interface and entering all his inputs.

I'm using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `CoreData` `Entity` instead of `Array` in `CoreData`? Like entity name: **Day** and day's attributes are: **string**, **int**, **int**, **double**, **bool**. I think it is more clear than save it into an array. If you want only 7 saved data, you can sort it and the 8th (last one) remove.

Comment: Yes, looks simpler! So using all attributes you mentioned but I need of course also to add the Date attribute as well. Thanks

Comment: You can store Date as a String, just convert to string to store it. When you will load it you just parse it as a Date

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your data model to some level. There are many reasons for this and it will make your life much easier.

What I would do:
Make sure you have a clear concept of what kind of data can be possibly stored in a `Day`
Create a model(Entity) with the fields(Attributes). Model: `Day` Fields: `All possible dataPoint that can be stored and retrieved and displayed`

For example your Entity is called Day
Your Attributes:

```
thoughtOfTheDay: String?
peopleAnnoyedMeToday: Int16?
waterTakenInLiters: Float?
happyToday: Bool?
...
```

This way you have a clear picture of what can be saved and retrieved so you can go and check every day and use the data that is not nil.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question. This is very simple then answered by @Daveloper

Comment: Ok thanks! The question I was asking myself is should I create one Entity with attributes (Date, String, Int, Bool) or create 2 entities linked together one called DateInput (attribute: date from a date pickerView) and 2nd entity Inputs (with all attributes: String, Int, Bool, etc) - I am new to CoreData and having multiple entities seems quickly increasing the complexity of the coding. What is your view?

Comment: As I stated before, you need to design your data-model to some level. It is already suspect that you use the day as model. There is not much that is really characteristic to a "day" other than calendar related things and you have Calendar for that. Your model should be called for what it is. Like for example weather; Which was on a "day" yes, but its not a day itself. Or messages which has a "date" but in both cases it should probably be a date Attribute. Date model could include stats and kpi's for a day, globally. So multiple models for what they are. And let them have date attribute.